# Insert PDF image in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, vector-graphics

I have a .doc which I will convert in PDF. In this .doc I have an image.

When I convert the doc to PDF and then zoom it, the images became ugly pixel-ized.

I found a tool that converted my bitmap .png image to vectorial .PDF image.

Now **how could I import the PDF image in MS Word** (that finally I will convert to PDF once again)**?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It isn't possible to insert PDF files into Word documents (I haven't tried Word 2010 yet, so I don't know if this has changed in Word 2010).

The only way to insert vector images into a Word document is by using the EPS (encapsulated postscript) file format.

## Converting a PDF to EPS

### Adobe Illustrator

Open the PDF file in Illustrator and save it as an EPS file.

### Adobe Acrobat Professional

Open the PDF file in Acrobat Pro and then Export it to EPS

```
File > Export > Postscript > Encapsulated Postscript
```

### Inkscape (Open source vector graphics program)

Open the PDF file in Inkscape and save it as an EPS file.

Comment: EPS is not the only way, Word supports WMF/EMF as well.

Comment: EPS support in Word can't be relied upon as a given. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/support-for-eps-images-has-been-turned-off-in-office-a069d664-4bcf-415e-a1b5-cbb0c334a840 for additional detail regarding Microsoft's decision(s) to limit support for EPS.

Comment: Note that support for EPS images has been turned off in Office since April 11, 2017. [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/support-for-eps-images-has-been-turned-off-in-office-a069d664-4bcf-415e-a1b5-cbb0c334a840).

Answer (score 1):

There's a Word add-in called [OnMerge PDFpasteup](https://onmerge.com/PDF%20Mashup.html) (free eval version available; use that if you just have a one-time need) that seamlessly grabs graphics from PDF files and copies into the Word doc. Bitmap images have whatever resolution the original image embedded in the PDF has. Vector images and text are converted to EMF so they're scalable in Word.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert a PDF page as an object in Office, you will get a poorly rendered raster graphic. You can insert it as a vector graphic as follows:

Starting with Office 2016 and [Microsoft 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-svg-images-in-microsoft-365-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c), Microsoft Office finally supports Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG). So you can convert your PDF to SVGs and insert them into your Office document.

You can use [`pdf2svg`](https://cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/) to convert your (multi-page) PDF into (multiple) SVGs:

```
pdf2svg input.pdf output_%d.svg all
```

Answer (score 0):

I have personally found that the following vector formats are supported in the latest version of Word (`Version 1902`):

- **EMF/WMF** or their compressed variants EMZ/WMZ: I have found that if you only work with Word files with a Windows only environment, this has the best support. The files render in Word usually exactly the way I expect it to be. However, generating and working with these files can be difficult on non-Windows environments. Even on Windows, the file will open in Paint, but it will be converted to raster.
- **SVG**: A cross-platform format, especially in browsers, and is sort of the native format for Inkscape. However, I have found rendering variations between Inkscape, browsers, and Word, so you should test it for yourself.
- **EPS**: A cross-platform format. Depending on the program that generated the file, it sometimes won't be able to render at all, or renders the image slightly differently. However, if it meets your needs, it may not be a bad option. [As mentioned in the comments, in recent versions the support is very limited, if at all.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/support-for-eps-images-has-been-turned-off-in-office-a069d664-4bcf-415e-a1b5-cbb0c334a840)

Answer (score 0):

**With MS Word versions 2010 and above:**

- Click Insert > Object in the Text group.
- For Outlook, click inside of the body of an item, such as an email message or calendar event.
- Click Create from File > Browse.
- Browse to the .pdf file you want to insert, and then click Open.
- Click OK.

**More options**

If you just want to reuse some of the text from a PDF—for example, a short passage—try copying and pasting it. Usually, you'll get plain text without the formatting.

With the PDF reflow feature available in Word 2013 and 2016, you can open and edit PDF content, such as paragraphs, lists, and tables, as Word documents. Word pulls the content from the fixed-format PDF document and flows that content into a .docx file while preserving as much of the layout information as it can. See [Edit PDF content in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-a-pdf-b2d1d729-6b79-499a-bcdb-233379c2f63a) to learn more.

Source: [Microsoft Knowledgebase](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-pdf-to-your-office-file-74819342-8f00-4ab4-bcbe-0f3df15ab0dc)

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.