# Insert PDF as word page

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-indesign

I have made an a4 sized poster with a lot of graphics in Adobe InDesign. Now I need to make a report about and I like to include it in the report (made in Word). But I prefer not having it as an image because I want the whole page filed. I do not need to edit this particular page in word.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to be more clear on what you need. What do you mean by `But I prefer not having it as an image because I want the whole page filed.` exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert PDF image in MS Word](https://superuser.com/questions/137999/insert-pdf-image-in-ms-word)

Comment: @stackprotector It's not a duplicate. That thread's from 2012, the information is outdated, see [Microsoft Knowledgebase article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-pdf-to-your-office-file-74819342-8f00-4ab4-bcbe-0f3df15ab0dc). Furthermore the OP isn't asking about inserting a PDF, but the question's vague - see Sandeep's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I use Office 2016 and Adobe Acrobat Pro DC, I just open up a word document then drag the .PDF I wanted into the document. This appears like a picture being insert into the document (actually it is an Acrobat Document Object) however you have the option to double click the 'picture' and it will open up the embedded document in adobe.

Answer (score 0):

An image can fill the entire page, your best option is to place the image in Word, set the text wrap to anything other than `In Line With Text` (I recommend `Tight`) then resize and place to suit you needs.

Answer (score 0):

**To insert a PDF into a Word file with MS Word versions 2010 and above:**

---

- Click Insert > Object in the Text group.
- For Outlook, click inside of the body of an item, such as an email message or calendar event.
- Click Create from File > Browse.
- Browse to the .pdf file you want to insert, and then click Open.
- Click OK.

**More options**

If you just want to reuse some of the text from a PDF—for example, a short passage—try copying and pasting it. Usually, you'll get plain text without the formatting.

With the PDF reflow feature available in Word 2013 and 2016, you can open and edit PDF content, such as paragraphs, lists, and tables, as Word documents. Word pulls the content from the fixed-format PDF document and flows that content into a .docx file while preserving as much of the layout information as it can. See [Edit PDF content in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-a-pdf-b2d1d729-6b79-499a-bcdb-233379c2f63a) to learn more.

---

*Source: [Microsoft Knowledgebase](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-pdf-to-your-office-file-74819342-8f00-4ab4-bcbe-0f3df15ab0dc)*