# Insert PDF into Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, office365

I need to add a PDF document to a Word document and preserve it's formatting. The PDF in question only has one page. Ideally I would like to add it similar to adding an Excel Object. I don't need to be able to edit it. It would be nice if the text would remain selectable once I export the entire document to PDF, but it would not be the end of the world if it didn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert PDF image in MS Word](https://superuser.com/questions/137999/insert-pdf-image-in-ms-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Acrobat you can export the PDF as a Word document then wrap whatever you want around it... Otherwise, you can add a PDF in Word by clicking Insert -> Object -> then selecting Adobe Acrobat Document.  I can't verify if this works without Acrobat on your computer or not though.